# Macbook Pro Retina suddenly stopped mounting Huawei USB modem

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, internet, modem

I recently bought a MacBook Pro Retina. The first day I was able to connect my Huawei E352 3G USB modem and it worked all the day. After a couple of day I needed 3G connection again, but my MacBook Pro Retina does not recognize the modem anymore. There is a micro SD card in it, and it also does not mount. The modem works with my iMac flawlessly. All the MacBook Pro Retina USB ports work flawlessly, and recognize any other devices (pen drive, Blu-Ray writer, USB 3 external hard drive).

Any ideas as to why the modem doesn't work anymore?

Comment: When you took it out the last time you used it, did you eject it first (right click and select Eject)?

Comment: Actually I am not sure whether I did so. I think rather not.

Comment: Does it work after rebooting the mac completely?

Comment: If you are using the modem just at home, you could create a wifi network from your iMac to the MacBook and just run it like that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that by pulling out the modem without safely ejecting it first, the MicroSD card became corrupted and/or the modem itself was damaged.

The simplest and quickest fix may be, unfortunately, to get a new modem.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but if it is corrupted, why does it work on any other device? I tried with my iMac and a PC and both the modem and the micro SD works.

Comment: That's something different... (and probably something you should've included in your question). Have you rebooted the computer in question?

Comment: Yes, I have. (Sorry, in my original question I mentioned that it works with my iMac.)

Answer (score -1):

The Huawei modems are terrible. But regarding your problem, I've had it too, and the good news is that there is an easy fix. Provided it's visible in Disk Utility, open Disk Utility and select your device and run Verify and Repair Disk permissions. Run both the root and the sub disk.

Comment: You want to run Disk Utility on an USB Modem?

Comment: Yes? the huawei usb modems all have a micro sd card, it works by repairing disk permissions!